# How to hide DIV in paging

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, show-hide

I have an `onclick` button that removes all DIV a result. But it only removes the DIV's that are in the paging 1. The other results are in paging 2.3 ... etc are not removed. How to solve it?

```
function removeDiv (){
    $('#divPlay').removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
}

<a onclick="removeDiv()">Remove</a>
```

Pagination 1: Ok -
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xowph.jpg]

Pagination 2: Error -
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBmBc.jpg]

Comment: You should provide also the html otherwise we have no clue to answer the question.

Comment: add a reference to this function when the pagination button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call remove div on pagination:

```
$('.pagination a').on("click", function(){
    removeDiv();
}}
```

However, if the table's data is being loaded dynamically, I would recommend putting the logic for hiding divs in the code where data is being loaded (or retrieved) rather than waiting until elements are available in the document.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap, dataTable, the query is loaded all at once, but dataTable creates the pagination.

How could it be done to the DIV's work in all pagination?

How to make the script understand that the pagination form a single query?

Comment: Can you share the code where you are retrieving the data similar to how the example here loads from a Text file?  
https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html  
  
You may be able to parse the data prior to creating the HTML elements using the plugin.

Comment: I managed to applying the function on click of tabs.
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
        var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        alert( data[0] +"'s salary is: "+ data[ 5 ] );
    } );

Thanks